# iOS settings URL changes in iOS 10.0 SDK

Tags: ios, compatibility

Now 'prefs:root=general&path=about' doesn't work in iOS 10.0 SDK.

Both methods:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 10_0, "Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead") NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
```

are failed.

Does anyone has solutions?

Comment: You are only permitted to open your own app's settings. Opening any other settings URL will result in an app rejection.

Comment: Really，I don't see any related info in 'What's New in iOS 10 (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html)'.